# How to display a missing field (as blank/null) when using snapshot?

Tags: flutter

The following code is throwing the error "type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'". Not all documents will have this field (type_of_bunny) so I just want to display blank/null in those situations.

```
    final data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String?, dynamic?>;
    return Column(
      children: [
        Text("Bunny: " + data["type_of_bunny"]),
```

Thank you for any ideas.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String' this error pops up when trying to access data from map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73467640/type-null-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-string-this-error-pops-up-when-trying-to)

Comment: No not quite :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
final data = snapshot.data!.data() as Map<String?, dynamic?>;
return Column(
  children: [
    Text("Bunny: " + (data["type_of_bunny"] ?? "").toString()),
  ],
);
```

The above should do it. You use the null operator(??) which checks if its left side is null and falls back to its right (in this case empty string "").

Comment:  You may want to mark this as the answer/upvote.

Comment: Thank you! (marked as the answer but can't upvote because I'm a newbie)